# Does anyone know of a solid method of converting midi to MP3 through VSTs with presets?

Tags: software, midi, vst

This might be a bit outside of the practice and theory group but I'll give it a shot.

I have a need to take some internally-generated MIDI files and convert them to MP3 or WAV, but would prefer to not use soundfonts, etc.

I would like to find a Windows based sequencer or utility that would let me configure preset instrument sounds/tracks with VST plug ins which then through command line, script, something... let me load up a preset, pass the MIDI file, and get back a rendered audio file. So if I have a MIDI as a quartet, I point it to the quartet preset with my VSTs configured, and out pops the rendering.

It doesn't have to be a batch as I can easily make something to run it in a loop, I just can't quite find this missing middle tool.

I can create tracks with presets in many of my sequencers and manually do this... but none seem to have the command line/automation I seek, and of the command line/automation tools I find, most of them are based on FM or SoundFonts based on GM instead of letting me get a little more creative.

Has anyone seen something like what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

[Max for Live](https://www.ableton.com/en/live/max-for-live/) may be what you're looking for. Max MSP is a graphic coding environment designed for multimedia programming and Max for Live allows it to connect to Abelton Live. I don't have personal experience with either of these products, but I do have experience with Pure Data, Max MSP's open-source cousin and it can split MIDI files and route them around. It also has command line capabilities and compatibility with Python. Then Abelton would handle your VSTs.

The group Icarus [released an album](http://motherboard.vice.com/blog/how-to-make-digital-albums-unique-generate-a-new-one-with-every-download) entitled "Fake Fish Distribution" in which each download was produced through a generative process in Max and rendered in Abelton. Maybe I'm mistaken about the specifics of this process, but if not it would seem that all the tools are there for you to do this.

Comment: I'll have to dig into this. I do have Albeton and stumbled upon Pure Data a few weeks ago but never went back to look at it in more detail.